# AND is better or using Internal "IF"

Tags: c#, null, logic-programming

In a situation like this:"

```
if ((metadata != null) && (metadata.TypeEnum != VariantInfoMetadata.CellTypeEnum.Status))
```

do you recommend to keep the code as it is above?  Or is it better to make a nested "if" statement and breaks the condition into two sections where "outer if" makes sure metadata is not null and inner if does the rest of the checking.  I think a nested if takes care of possible null reference exception if value of metadata gets null.

Comment: A general answer depends on several factors. For example, how many conditions do you have to test for? Whether you care about handling each condition outcome separately? Would individual conditions be tested again down the road in your code?

Comment: If you want to handle "metadata == null" case as an exception you would want to create an if for that. if(metadata == null) throw new exception() ..

Comment: the && operator is short circuited so you won't get a null reference exception in either scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` in many languages (C, C++, Java, C#) are *short-circuiting*, which means that as soon as the answer is known, it stops evaluating. If your language is one of short-circuiting languages, you do not need a nested `if`, because as soon as `metadata != null` evaluates to `false`, the evaluation of the overall expression is going to stop, preventing the null referencing. In fact, short-circuiting (logical) `AND`s and `OR`s were invented specifically to deal with situations like you describe without the need to create an additional level of nesting.

Comment: yes it is C#...

Comment: @BDotA The you are good.

Answer (score 17):

What you have there is perfect.  It's clear and simple.

If you had several cases testing for null, I'd combine them.  This is bad as it tests for `(metadata != null)` repeatedly.

```
if ((metadata != null) && (metadata.TypeEnum != CellTypeEnum.Status))
{ ... }
else if ((metadata != null) && (metadata.TypeEnum != CellTypeEnum.Info))
{ ... }
else if ((metadata != null) && (metadata.TypeEnum != CellTypeEnum.Blank))
{ ... }
```

This is better:

```
if (metadata != null)
{
    if (metadata.TypeEnum != CellTypeEnum.Status)
    { ... }
    else if (metadata.TypeEnum != CellTypeEnum.Info)
    { ... }
    else if (metadata.TypeEnum != CellTypeEnum.Blank)
    { ... }
}
```

Or even better for enums:

```
if (metadata != null)
{
    switch (metadata.TypeEnum) {
        case CellTypeEnum.Status:
            //do stuff
            break;
        case CellTypeEnum.Info:
            //do stuff
            break;
        case CellTypeEnum.Blank:
            //do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically keeping it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to use the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Instead of explicit checks for null, you always return an instance, so in this case you'd have (pseudo-code):

```
public class NullMetadata
{
    VariantInfoMetadata TypeEnum { get; set; }

    public NullMetadata()
    {
        TypeEnum = VariantInfoMetadata.None
    }
}
```

Then instead of

```
var metadata = null
```

you'd have

```
var metadata = new NullMetadata()
```

And the check for VariantInfoMetadata.CellTypeEnum.Status would always return false.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to keep statements inside an if clause as concise as possible, many times limiting
them to boolean variables with meaningful names, such as:

```
bool isCellTypeStatus = //...
if (isCellTypeStatus) { ... }
```

And the boolean variable declaration will span more than one line
so that programmer eye focus will not trail to far away characters.

```
bool isCellTypeStatus = 
       metadata != null &&
       metadata.TypeEnum != VariantInfoMetadata.CellTypeEnum.Status;
```

It separates two mental evaluations of the condition and the outcome,
to two separate statements, thus increasing the speed another programmer will
consume your code.

Answer (score 1):

Another factor to add to [dasblinkenlight](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/44705/dasblinkenlight) (wich I think it's the best answer) I could add that is more readable to put sentences into a single if than nested if rules which are prone to errors

Answer (score 1):

Because of short-circuit evaluation, both solutions are equally valid technically.  However, stylistically, it's usually preferable and possible to arrange for variables like `metadata` never to be `null` in the first place.

In this particular case, you are using two variables to denote type.  `metadata.TypeEnum` stores the type, and `metadata` itself being `null` denotes a "no metadata at all" type.  Your programming language lets you create as many types as you want.  Take advantage of it.

A better solution is to create a `Cell` base class that doesn't even have a `metadata` member, so there's no need for it to ever be `null`.  Then create a `StatusCell` derived class that adds any unique properties you need, and same for the other types of cells.

If that kind of refactoring isn't possible, like if you're working with a third-party API, another option to consider is a guard clause, like:

```
if (metadata == null)
    return;

if (metadata.TypeEnum != VariantInfoMetadata.CellTypeEnum.Status)
    ...
```

A lot of people (including myself), prefer this style because it limits both the level of nesting and the number of conditions in one `if` statement.

Comment: Cue *Religious Wars* about multiple exit points... :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple conditions for a "success" I prefer it if the conditions are checked in one `if` block, rather than in nested statements.

But.....

For readability sometimes I prefer this:

```
isOfOAge = age >= 16;
isSober = bloodAchohol = 0; // this calculated is wasteful if `isOfOAge` is false
canDrive = isOfAge && isSober;
if(canDrive).......
```

The readability does make for a wasteful check on `isSober` even if `isOfAGe` is false. Assuming the boolean calculations are very expensive a nested `if` could provide for nice variable names as well as the short circuit effect.

My recommendation is DO NOT put this into a coding standard. It's not wrong to nest. It's not wrong to use short circuiting. Both could lead to better readability in certain situations.

Comment: The main advantage of short-circuiting in this case isn't a performance gain, it's that the second condition will throw an exception if the first is `false`.

Comment: With short-ciruiting not all conditions get evaluated. In your example all conditions do get evaluated. Evaluation can have side-effects, so it's different logic.

Answer (score 0):

**In short,** for C# language it is better to keep it as is.

The evaluation of your mentioned statement will stop and get `false` value once `metadata is null`.

Nested if statements are hard to maintain, and it is better to skip them if application logic does not require them. Or in another words, there might be a number of ways how to formulate nested if statements in more readable and maintainable syntax.